# Unity - How can I fix this code so it works without transform.position = newPosition?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller, move

so my character has to walk around a tower, simple

but me being stupid can only work it out by using transform.position in update so jumping and collisions ofc, dont work

here is the tower concept ( see image )
[Tower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj7z3.png)

here is how it works rn (see video: https://streamable.com/7tmq1l)

You will see in the clip how bad it breaks if i comment the transform.position = newposition to allow for jumping

Here is my code I used:

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float radius = 7;
    [SerializeField] private float angleSpeed = 28;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 5;
    private float angle;

    Rigidbody rb;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0);
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        angle -= horizontalInput * angleSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        Vector3 newPosition = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0) * new Vector3(0, 0, radius);

        transform.position = newPosition;

        //jump
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)|| Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            Debug.Log("Jumping!");
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
```

Ofc the jumping doesnt work because of this

Comment: You angle is horizontal but the vector3 radius is applied to the Z-Axis.  I would think new Vector3(radius, radius , 0)

Comment: Thats a fair spot.
How do I remove the transform.position whilst retaining this movement around a radius based on an angle to allow for jumping and collision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adjust the XZ position using the rigidBody and let the rb adjust the Y axis.

```
   Vector3 newPosition = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0) * radius;
   newPosition.Y = rb.position.Y; // leave Y unchanged to allow for jumps
   rb.position = newPosition;
```